# Bin Packing Algorithm In Need of Speeding-Up

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, backtracking

I'm looking for an intelligent way to approach a version of the common bin-packing problem. Given a number of bags (as I'm calling them) with a certain capacity, and list of items that take up a certain amount of space, the task is to determine if all of the items can fit in the bags; and if so, how. I've got an exhaustive DFS working right now, but it takes... forever. My DFS is iterative and requires copying entire states at every step, which is very expensive. Here's my code for a specific problem with 4 bags with 10 capacity (the truly relevant portions of this code are just the pack() method and the State class if you don't want to look at it all):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class BagProblem {
    int numBags;
    int bagCapacity;
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BagProblem bp = new BagProblem(4, 10);
        bp.pack();
    }

    public BagProblem(int numBags, int bagCapacity) {
        this.numBags = numBags;
        this.bagCapacity = bagCapacity;
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Item("item0", 6));
        items.add(new Item("item1", 6));
        items.add(new Item("item2", 6));
        items.add(new Item("item5", 3));
        items.add(new Item("item6", 3));
        items.add(new Item("item7", 3));
        items.add(new Item("item8", 2));
        items.add(new Item("item9", 2));
        items.add(new Item("item10", 2));
        items.add(new Item("item11", 2));
        items.add(new Item("item12", 2));
        items.add(new Item("item13", 2));
        items.add(new Item("item14", 1));
    }

    // find a valid way to pack and print the items in each Bag, or
    // print failure
    public void pack() {
        Stack <State> s = new Stack<State>();
        Bag[] currBags = new Bag[numBags];
        for (int i = 0; i < numBags; i++) {
            currBags[i] = new Bag(bagCapacity);
        }
        s.push(new State(currBags));
        while(!s.isEmpty()) {
            State currState = s.pop();
            for (Item i : items) {
                if (!currState.containsItem(i)) {
                    State newState = new State(currState.bags);
                    newState.numItems = currState.numItems;
                    if (newState.addItem(i)) {
                        s.push(newState);
                        if (newState.numItems == items.size()) {
                            System.out.println("success");
                            System.out.println(newState);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("failure");
    }

    private class State {
        Bag[] bags;
        int numItems;

        public State(Bag[] currBags) {
            bags = new Bag[numBags];
            for (int i = 0; i < numBags; i++) {
                bags[i] = new Bag(bagCapacity);
            }

            // figure out how to actually copy this
            for (int j = 0; j < numBags; j++) {
                Bag bagToCopy = currBags[j];
                for (Item item : bagToCopy.contents) {
                    Item newItem = new Item(item.name, item.size);
                    bags[j].size = bagToCopy.size;
                    bags[j].contents.add(newItem);
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean addItem(Item i) {
            for (Bag b : bags) {
                if (b.addItem(i)) {
                    numItems++;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public boolean containsItem(Item i) {
            for (Bag b : bags) {
                for (Item item : b.contents) {
                    if (item.name.equals(i.name))
                        return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String output = "";
            for (Bag b : bags) {
                for (Item j : b.contents) {
                    output += j.name + " ";
                }
                output += "\n";
            }
            return output;
        }

    }

    private class Bag {
        int capacity;
        int size;
        ArrayList<Item> contents;

        public Bag(int capacity) {
            this.capacity = capacity;
            this.size = 0;
            contents = new ArrayList<Item>();
        }

        public boolean addItem(Item i) {
            if(size + i.size > capacity)
                return false;
            contents.add(i);
            size += i.size;
            return true;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String output = "";
            for (Item i : contents) {
                output += i.name + " ";
            }
            return output + "\n";
        }

    }

    private class Item {
        String name;
        int size;

        public Item(String name, int size) {
            this.name = name;
            this.size = size;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

    }
}
```

After approximately one million years, this does spit out a correct answer (you probably won't want to actually wait that long if you try to run this):

```
success
item14 item7 item6 item5 
item13 item12 item2 
item11 item10 item1 
item9 item8 item0
```

Each line indicates a separate bag. How can I speed this up? I know there are heuristics about trying to place the largest item first, etc., but what I'm really interested in is getting the basic DFS (or maybe I should try backtracking?) to have less overhead; I'll try to get fancier later.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Have you tried looking on Google and Wikipedia for algorithms? For example the first-fit-algoirthm can produce an answer very fast, but it will not be optimal

Comment: The problem is that there's a bit of a twist on this bin-packing problem. I need to know if a given number of bags with a certain capacity can contain a set of items of certain size; first-fit and other non-optimal algorithms won't be able to tell. I think DFS or backtracking has gotta be the only way to do it, but its just so slooooow. Granted, a different arrangement of the items and bags that are tried first might help, but right now I'm worried I'm copying more information at each step than I really need to, which is killing my run-time.

Comment: What's the twist?  You're describing exactly the standard bin-packing problem.  This problem is NP-hard, so any solution that guarantees to find an optimal answer will be slow on large instances.  But if first-fit or a different heuristic packs the items into k bags, you know that the optimal answer is at most k, and you may be able to prove it can't be k-1 or less (e.g. if the total size of the items exceeds (k-1)*bag_size), in which case you'll know the answer is optimal.

Comment: Well, I've typically seen the problem phrased as "How many bins will this take?", which gives you some wiggle room on optimality, rather than "Can this number of bins work?" Not really a twist, I guess, but I don't think there's any short-cutting with first-fit or other algorithms that will reliably get the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use Java but your implementation seems quite inefficient (as you've mentioned yourself) due to overcomplicating it. The algorithm itself is also very strange, I did not attempt to replicate it and just used the obvious O(bags^items) brute force algorithm that tries to put the first item into each bag, for each of those cases tries to put the second item into each bag, etc...

Instead of replicating the entire state repeatedly on the stack, you can *put an item in a bag*, explore the branch of the tree with this change, then *take the item out of the bag*.

Here is an example that completes instantly for your test case in C#.

```
    static int[] itemSize;
    static int[] bagFreeSpace;
    static bool[,] doesBagContainItem; // in case this looks weird, [,] is a matrix, in java it would be [][]

    static bool pack(int item)
    { 
        // output the solution if we're done
        if (item == itemSize.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bagFreeSpace.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("bag" + i);
                for (int j = 0; j < itemSize.Length; j++)
                    if (doesBagContainItem[i, j])
                        Console.Write("item" + j + "(" + itemSize[j] + ") ");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return true;
        }

        // otherwise, keep traversing the state tree
        for (int i = 0; i < bagFreeSpace.Length; i++)
        {
            if (bagFreeSpace[i] >= itemSize[item])
            {
                doesBagContainItem[i,item] = true; // put item into bag
                bagFreeSpace[i] -= itemSize[item];
                if (pack(item + 1))                 // explore subtree
                    return true;
                bagFreeSpace[i] += itemSize[item];  // take item out of the bag
                doesBagContainItem[i,item] = false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        itemSize = new int[] { 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
        bagFreeSpace = new int[] { 10, 10, 10, 10 };
        doesBagContainItem = new bool[bagFreeSpace.Length, itemSize.Length];

        if (!pack(0))
            Console.WriteLine("No solution");
    }
```

Note: if you want to parallelize execution, you need to give each worker its own copy of the state (or 1 copy per job), but only at the point of branching, they can still then proceed as above, without replicating the state.